# Can I verify my domain once in AWS SES and allow my other accounts to use this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I have successfully verified my domain in AWS SES on one account. I would like my other accounts to send from this domain, and as such I have created an Authorization policy with this in mind (via Terraform):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
 statement {
   actions   = ["ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail"]
   resources = ["${aws_ses_domain_identity.this.arn}"]
   effect    = "Allow"

   principals {
     identifiers = ["123456789100", "1234567890101", "1234567890102"]
     type        = "AWS"
   }
  }
}
```

and attached this to the verified domain.

However, when I try to send from another account (listed in the identifiers group above) I am unable to send, being given an error:

```
554 Access denied: User `arn:aws:iam::1234567890101:user/ses_user' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendRawEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:1234567890101:identity/my.name@domain.com'
```

The ses_user on that account has the following IAM policy (again, in TF):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_user" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

I was under the impression that cross-account email sending was possible here. Am I mistaken? Perhaps I am missing something.

Thanks

sources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-authorization-policy-examples.html
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy

Answer (score 0):

No responses, but I understand that it is possible to do this with delegated senders. The SMTP sender user needs to include X headers in the email when it is sent (these are stripped by SES before being sent). The verified domain then simply requires the SES Auth policy to allow the account ID of the delegated account to send emails. This can be bundled with other conditions (ie can only send to certain destinations) in the same policy, as per here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-identity-owner-tasks-policy.html

See also:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-delegate-sender-tasks-email.html

I chose not to go down this road, but it is possible.

For an example of how to insert Headers, you might be using Postfix for example in which case use header_checks with the prepend directive:

http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html